# How can you resize a 1-D array to a 2-D array in C# without copying?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

As far as I know, a 2-D array is laid out in memory exactly like a 1-D array, it just uses different indexing. So given that, it seems like there must be some way (probably unsafe) in C# to convert a 1-D array to a 2-D array without actually copying elements, assuming you want the elements from the 1-D array to translate to the 2-D array in a row-first manner. I did figure out how to accomplish this with a single copy command, but it still seems like more processing than is necessary:

```
int[] onedim = new int[] { 5, 3, 6, 2, 1, 5 };
int[,] twodim = new int[2, 3];
GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(twodim, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
Marshal.Copy(onedim, 0, pointer, onedim.Length);
pinnedArray.Free();
```

Is there some way that I could tell C#, treat this 1-D array as a 2-D array with these dimensions instead? Unsafe code is fine. If not, is this a limitation of the language or is there some fundamental problem I am missing?

Comment: How will the array by used once it is converted to a 2D array?

Comment: @AaronRoberts Not sure what you mean. It should behave exactly like if you had declared the 2-D array inline e.g. `int[,] twodim = new int[,] { { 5, 3, 6 }, { 2, 1, 5 } }`.

Comment: Are you creating the initial int[] or is someone else?

Comment: @Moop Somebody else. It's being passed to me from a C DLL.

Comment: Can you show the signature of the external method that is providing the array?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to define a class that accesses the underlying 1D array

```
public class Array2D<T>
{
    private readonly T[] _data;
    private readonly Int32 _dimX;
    private readonly Int32 _dimY;

    public Array2D(T[] data, Int32 dimX, Int32 dimY)
    {
        _data = data;
        _dimX = dimX;
        _dimY = dimY;
    }

    public T this [Int32 x, Int32 y]
    {
        get { return _data[x * _dimY + y]; }
        set { _data[x * _dimY + y] = value; }
    }
}

var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
var array2d = new Array2D<Int32>(array, 2, 3);

Assert.AreEqual(array2d[0, 0], array[0]);
Assert.AreEqual(array2d[0, 1], array[1]);
Assert.AreEqual(array2d[0, 2], array[2]);
Assert.AreEqual(array2d[1, 0], array[3]);
Assert.AreEqual(array2d[1, 1], array[4]);
Assert.AreEqual(array2d[1, 2], array[5]);
```

My indexing might be backwards, however this wold behave like a 2D array while maintaining the 1D array reference.

edit: Indexing was backwards, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(onedim, 0, twodim, 0, onedim.Length * sizeof(int));
```

It accepts multidimensional arrays as well.

Comment: Block copy is still a copy.

Comment: While it still does a copy this is certainly helpful as it's a lot simpler than what I came up with.

Comment: @Mitch Sure! There are only two options: copy or wrap with a class that has a 2-D indexer. Each one has its own pros and cons. But only the copy will give a 2-D array, that can be passed as args to methods which accepts, for instance, `T[,]`.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is "How can you resize a 1-D array to a 2-D array in C# without copying?".  I'm not saying that your answer is not helpful, I'm saying that it doesn't answer the question as asked.  You may consider adding the caveat "I'm not aware of any means to do so without copying, but..."

Answer (score 0):

Use [Marshal.PtrToStructure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx).

I couldn't figure out how to do it without wrapping the 2d array in structure, but the following works without a copy.

```
    struct array2d 
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
        int[,] data;
    };


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] onedim = new int[] { 5, 3, 6, 2, 1, 5 };

        array2d twoDim;

        unsafe
        {
            fixed (int* p = onedim)
            {
                twoDim = Marshal.PtrToStructure<array2d>(new IntPtr(p));
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What if the size of 1-D array is not a compile-time const? And in your sample what are the dimensions of `array2d.data`: [1,6], [2,3], [3,2], [6,1]?

Comment: @Dmitry oddly when viewed in the debugger, the array2d.data is a 1d array. Though the compiler allows accessing `twoDim.data[0,0]` I get an index out of bounds error.

Comment: PtrToStructure still performs a copy.

Comment: @Mitch it doesn't say it copies in the docs. Do you have reference?

Comment: You are passing an unmanaged pointer and it is returning a managed struct, that requires a copy.  [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx) "The following example creates a managed structure, transfers it to unmanaged memory, and then transfers it back to managed memory using the PtrToStructure method. "